# ASP.Net: Showing buttons only to logged in users

Tags: asp.net, button, authentication, hide, show

I want to show a few buttons to users who are logged in. I don't use Membership Provider but Session.

Can I still somehow use LoggedInTemplateor should I do it some other way?

I store the session user like this in OnLogin button event:

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) FROM Admin Where     username='"+Username.Text+"' AND password='"+Password.Text+"'", conn);

    conn.Open();
    int result = (int)query.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();


    if (result > 0){
        Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
        Session["User"]=Username.Text;
    }
    else Session["LoggedIn"] = false;
```

Then i try to create button if user is logged in:

```
if ((bool)Session["LoggedIn"]==true)) Button_dodaj_oglas.Visible = true;
    else Button_dodaj_oglas.Visible = false;
```

but I get Objject not set to an instance (concerning Session). WTF?

Comment: What's wrong with `Button1.Visible = (bool)Session("LoggedIn");`

Comment: please consider doing 2 minutes testing before asking such questions

Comment: I tried
     if (Session("LoggedIn") == true) Btn1.Visible = true;

But got *The name Session doesn't exist in current context*..

Comment: Session might not be saved on login button event.

Comment: OnLogin button event saves the state like this (isn't it correct?):
-- pasted the code in my original post

Comment: You can get the Session object(even in static context) with `HttpContext.Current.Session`. I'm not sure why _"name Session doesn't exist in current context"_.

Comment: @PrimožKralj: Have you debugged to see if Session is null or your Button? I assume the latter. Are you creating this button or is it declared on aspx markup? Show us the relevant part of your code/markup.

Comment: Actually I think I knwo what could be wrong - I am asking for Session["LoggedIn"] in Page_Load of my Default.aspx; but I am creating Session value with key LoggedIn only when user click Login button. So there is no LoggedIn Key in Session and that's why Null Exception - I think. But this is now catch 22 - how to check then? :) Somehow I should make Session["LoggedIn"] = false only for the first time.

The button is created in aspx markup so it can't be null.

Comment: @PrimožKralj: Then you only have to check for `null`: `if(Session["LoggedIn"]!=null && (bool)Session["LoggedIn"]){}`.

Comment: Tim, thanks. Please post this to a new answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Session` to store the loggedin-status although i would not recommend it, because [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) **is not** [`Authentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx).

```
bool loggedIn = Session["LoggedIn"] != null && (bool)Session["LoggedIn"];
Button1.Visible = loggedIn;
```

Comment: Thank you. Since it's only for learning purposes I will still go with this code.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can store login status inside session & then toggle individual
   controls/Control blocks but again that is not a good approach I
   think ( you can refer Tim's comment for that)
2. I recommend you to  render a toolbar or menu via database according to user role level so there is not much work involved at design level